# How do you swordfight in Tintin: Secret of the Unicorn?

Tags: keyboard, tintin

I was playing the pc game called Tintin, secret of the Unicorn in which there is a scene where Captain Haddock is sword-fighting with some enemies. The problem is that the only keys that seem to work are the <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd> keys and they are only used for defending from attacks. I tried all the other keys and none of them do anything.

So any idea how we can fight back during these sword fights? Which keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just move your mouse forward in order to attack, without pressing any keys, which serve only to defend.

Comment: Thanks. Never would have guessed that. For some reason it takes a lot of time before he actually attacks. I guess that's why I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Oh forgot to mention that moving my mouse around right-and-left also worked for me.